# How to take total count from selected checkbox while using from Collection C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

In my page, there are check boxes multiple check boxes with values. I am taking this values from collection. I want to take the particular selected check box total count.

I tried the following code, But i am getting an error.

```
foreach (string key in collection.AllKeys)
        {
         var selectedCount = Convert.ToInt32(collection.GetValues(Convert.ToInt32(collection.AllKeys)).Contains("true"));
        }
```

If i use the above code, the result is showing error like

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.

Give me some suggestions to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the total and subtotal

```
int totalSelected = 0;
foreach (string key in collection.AllKeys)
{
    int subTotalSelected = collection.GetValues(key).Where(x => x.Contains("true")).Count();
    totalSelected += subTotalSelected;
}
```